# PS Script won't run on server, runs in ISE and when pasted into PS window

Tags: powershell

I have a PS Script I'm trying to run on a Hyper-V 2012 server. The idea is to have a basic menu that launches one of several possible management utilities. When I paste the contents into the open PowerShell window, it works fine. It also runs in ISE. When I try and run it from the .ps1 on the server, it gives this error:

```
PS C:\> C:\Mgmt\MgmtSel.ps1
At C:\Mgmt\MgmtSel.ps1:70 char:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
At C:\Mgmt\MgmtSel.ps1:72 char:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
At C:\Mgmt\MgmtSel.ps1:73 char:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

I have looked at the referenced lines, and the closed brackets seem appropriate to me. I've tried changing them, and it still won't run, as well as breaking it in ISE. Any guidance or ideas would be much appreciated!!

Here are the broken lines, 70 - 73:

```
}
default { $global:xExitSession=$true;break }
}
}
```

Here is the script in it's entirety:

```
<######################################################################

Present user with options to launch one of several management programs
Save as MgmtSel.ps1 in c:\Mgmt

v 0.1   Basic Menu Presentation for different management tools

Written By Ricky Carleton
Based on code by Paul Westlake

######################################################################>
$xAppName    = ‘MgmtSel’
[BOOLEAN]$global:xExitSession=$false
function LoadMenuSystem(){
[INT]$xMenu1=0
[INT]$xMenu2=0
[BOOLEAN]$xValidSelection=$false
while ( $xMenu1 -lt 1 -or $xMenu1 -gt 4 ){
CLS
#… Present the Menu Options
Write-Host “`n`tLogin Management Tools Selection – Version 0.1`n” -ForegroundColor Magenta
Write-Host “`t`tPlease select the admin area you require`n” -Fore Cyan
Write-Host “`t`t`t1. sconfig console” -Fore Cyan
Write-Host “`t`t`t2. Corefig” -Fore Cyan
Write-Host “`t`t`t3. Hyper-V Mgmt” -Fore Cyan
Write-Host “`t`t`t4. Quit and exit`n” -Fore Cyan
#… Retrieve the response from the user
[int]$xMenu1 = Read-Host “`t`tEnter Menu Option Number”
if( $xMenu1 -lt 1 -or $xMenu1 -gt 4 ){
Write-Host “`tPlease select one of the options available.`n” -Fore Red;start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
}
Switch ($xMenu1){    #… User has selected a valid entry.. load next menu
1 { 
CLS
Write-Host “`t`tStarting sconfig`n” -Fore Cyan
start c:\Windows\System32\sconfig.cmd
}
2 {
CLS
Write-Host “`t`tStarting Corefig`n” -Fore Cyan
C:\Corefig\COREFIG.PS1
}
3 {
while ( $xMenu2 -lt 1 -or $xMenu2 -gt 3 ){
CLS
# Present the Menu Options
Write-Host “`n`tSelect the Hyper-V Mgmt Tool you would like to use`n” -Fore Cyan
Write-Host “`t`t`t1. PSHVM30” -Fore Green
Write-Host “`t`t`t2. ProHVM (not working yet)” -Fore Green
Write-Host “`t`t`t3. Go to Main Menu`n” -Fore Green
[int]$xMenu2 = Read-Host “`t`tEnter Menu Option Number”
if( $xMenu1 -lt 1 -or $xMenu1 -gt 3 ){
Write-Host “`tPlease select one of the options available.`n” -Fore Red;start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
}
Switch ($xMenu2){
1 { 
CLS
Write-Host “`t`tStarting PSHVM`n” -Fore Cyan
call powershell -WindowStyle Hidden C:\PSHVM30\hyperv.ps1
}
2 { 
CLS
Write-Host “`t`tStarting Corefig (For now, later, ProHVM)`n” -Fore Cyan
start C:\Corefig\COREFIG.PS1
}
default { Write-Host “`n`tYou Selected Option 3 – Go to Main Menu`n” -Fore Yellow; break}
}
}
default { $global:xExitSession=$true;break }
}
}

LoadMenuSystem
If ($xExitSession){
Exit-PSSession    #… User quit & Exit
} Else {
C:\Mgmt\MgmtSel.ps1    #… Loop the function
}
```

Comment: As a side note, it would aid debugging, if you indented all code blocks with a relevant number of spaces.

Comment: I actually based this off someone else's multiple select code instead of writing my own. =/ Maybe this is just what I get? I was going to pretty it up once it was working. It would probably help to do it sooner though. Thanks again for looking.

Comment: I took the hint, and re-wrote the entire thing myself. I can't tell what the difference is, but it works now. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to terminate all your `break` statements with a semicolon `;` - see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and for your time! Still no joy.

Comment: @MagnaVis: Make sure all statements are terminated with `;`. Add indentation. If no luck - start removing statements one by one, see when the error goes away. Just some general debugging procedures there.